# Looping thru elements, changing z index, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I have a set of elements with that are draggable with jquery. All draggable elements belong to the "element" class.

Each time an element is moved, I want to loop through all elements and change the z-index to 5, and then change the element being dragged z-index to 10, so that the dragged element will always be on top.

This is what I currently have but it is not working.

```
mousedown(function(){
        var myObj = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
        for(var i =0, il = myObj.length; i<il; i++){
            myObj[i].style.zIndex='5';
        }
        $(this).style.zIndex='10';
 })
```

How can I force `$(this)` to be displayed on top of all other elements in the `element` class?

Comment: it should be `this.style.zIndex='10';`

Comment: If it were me, I would keep the z index the same and reorder the dom instead so the last dragged is moved to the end and thus on top. That way the stacking order of the other dragging elements remain the same, assuming the non dragging elements can overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` refers to a jQuery object, not a document object. Use `this.style.zIndex="10";` instead.

Since you did not invoke any jQuery, there is no `$(this)` to reference!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the css and element structure not much is possible, but whatever you have done can be written as

```
$('.element').not(this).css('zIndex', 5);
$(this).css('zIndex', 10);
//or this.style.zIndex='10';
```

The `style` property belongs to the dom element, $(this) refers to the jQuery wrapper for the dom element refered by `this`. So either you can set the style property directly using `this.style` or use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to do this.

Also you can use the class selector to select and change all the elements zIndex instead of writing a loop yourself

Comment: +1 Although it could be even shorter ;) No real reason to do `.not(this)` as you overwrite the value on `this` the following line.